# BootstrapValidator skip validation if empty

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these rules here for example:

```
ducationStartYear: {
                validators: {
                    numeric: {
                        message: 'The year must be numeric'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 4,
                        message: 'The year must be exact 4 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            EducationEndYear: {
                validators: {
                    numeric: {
                        message: 'The year must be numeric'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 4,
                        message: 'The year must be exact 4 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            QualificationMonth: {
                validators: {
                    numeric: {
                        message: 'The month must be numeric'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                        max: 2,
                        message: 'month year must be exact 2 numbers long'
                    }
                }
            },
            QualificationYear: {
                validators: {
                    numeric: {
                        message: 'The year must be numeric'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 4,
                        message: 'The year must be exact 4 numbers long'
                    }
                }
            },
            JobStartDate: {
                validators: {
                    date: {
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                        max: 'JobEndDate',
                        message: 'The date is not valid'
                    }
                }
            },
            JobEndDate: {
                validators: {
                    date: {
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                        min: 'JobStartDate',
                        message: 'The date is not valid'
                    }
                }
            },
```

Fieldset:

```
 <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="Surname">Month / Year</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <?php echo "<input type='text' name='QualificationMonth' class='form-control' placeholder=''value=".$Submission['QualificationMonth'].">" ;?>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
                    <?php echo "<input type='text' name='QualificationYear' class='form-control' placeholder=''value=".$Submission['QualificationYear'].">" ;?>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

As you can see, I have not set them to be required. But the validator alarms if left empty. I would like the validator to skip those field if they left empty. But if the user type something to have a look on the input. How's that possible?

EDIT:
I got a bit deeper and the real issue is that, when I insert record to the database using the same form, if the textbox is empty it sends to database a value of 0.
Im using the same form to fetch the details back to the form and allow modifications. When I fetch the inserted detail on the form, those specific textboxes appear with 0's. This is when the valitations alarm.

So the issue is in the creating the row in the database.

Solved: I just put an if statement to make the '' variables to NULL, so when i fetch the details back to the form, the field is empty and not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I just put an if statement to make the '' variables to NULL, so when i fetch the details back to the form, the field is empty and not 0.